# Oracle error when parsing XML data: LPX-00663

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, xml-parsing

Im getting below error, can anyone please help me resolve it.

> **the ORA-31011: the XML parsing failed The  the ORA-19202: the Error
>   Occurred in the XML processing support  The LPX-00663:. VM
>   String-Stack overflow**

I could see solution as **Increase the size bed of the VM StringStack in XmlXslVMCreate ()**  in some websites but no steps given on how to do it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `v_xml := v_xml.transform(v_xsl)`

Comment: below statement throws error:SELECT Xmltransform(l_xml_xmltype, l_xslt).getclobval() INTO l_xml_clob FROM dual;

Comment: Maybe you should show your code (edit the question and format it; don't try to put everything in comments), and include sample values for the variables you're using when you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle Documentation.

> PL/SQL package DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR provides a convenient and efficient
>   way of applying a single style sheet to multiple documents.  The
>   performance of this package is better than that of method transform(),
>   because the style sheet is parsed only once.

I had the same problem. Workaround was. Something like this.

```
DECLARE
  v_out_clob       CLOB;
  v_in_xml        XMLTYPE;
  v_in_xsl        XMLTYPE;
  ctx_xslproc     dbms_xslprocessor.processor;
  v_in_xsl_dd       dbms_xmldom.DOMDocument;
  v_in_xml_dd       dbms_xmldom.DOMDocument;
  v_styleshet       dbms_xslprocessor.stylesheet;
BEGIN

   v_in_xml := new xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><document></document>');
  v_in_xsl := new xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
                                   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
                                     <xsl:output method="html" />
                                     <xsl:template match="/">
                                       <html>
                                         <head>
                                           <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
                                         </head>
                                         <body>
                                           <br />
                                         </body>
                                       </html>
                                     </xsl:template>
                                   </xsl:stylesheet>');
  ctx_xslproc   := dbms_xslprocessor.newProcessor;
  v_in_xsl_dd  := dbms_xmldom.newDOMDocument(v_in_xsl);
  v_in_xml_dd  := dbms_xmldom.newDOMDocument(v_in_xml);
  v_styleshet  := dbms_xslprocessor.newStyleSheet(v_in_xsl_dd, NULL);
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_out_clob,FALSE);
  dbms_xslprocessor.processXSL(ctx_xslproc,v_styleshet,v_in_xml_dd,v_out_clob);
  dbms_xmldom.freeDocument(v_in_xsl_dd);
  dbms_xmldom.freeDocument(v_in_xml_dd);
  dbms_xslprocessor.freeProcessor(ctx_xslproc);  
  dbms_output.put_line(v_out_clob);

END;
```